# how to shared viewmodel in compose navigation using koin injection?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is my code. Does anyone know how to implement a shared view model using Koin in compose navigation? This ViewModel creates a new instance for two screens in compose navigation when I use this code. Might I be missing something in this approach?

Thank you!

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                NavigationSystem()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigationSystem() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "scan") {
        composable("scan") {
            val viewModel: BLEIoTViewModel = it.sharedViewModel(navController)
            val state by viewModel.advertisementState.collectAsState()

            ScanScreen(
                state,
                viewModel,
                onNavigateToConfig = { navController.navigate("config") },
            )
        }
        composable("config") {
            val viewModel: BLEIoTViewModel = it.sharedViewModel(navController)
            val state by viewModel.advertisementState.collectAsState()
            BLEIoTConfigurationScreen(viewModel, state)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> NavBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(
    navController: NavHostController,
): T {
    val navGraphRoute = destination.parent?.route ?: return koinViewModel()

    val parentEntry = remember(navGraphRoute) {
        navController.getBackStackEntry(navGraphRoute)
    }

    return koinViewModel(
        viewModelStoreOwner = parentEntry
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [`NavHost` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/compose/package-summary#NavHost(androidx.navigation.NavHostController,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1)) you'll see these parameters:

```
@Composable
fun NavHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.Center,
    route: String? = null, // <-------- Look at this one
    enterTransition: AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> EnterTransition = { fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(700)) },
    exitTransition: AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> ExitTransition = { fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(700)) },
    popEnterTransition: AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> EnterTransition = enterTransition,
    popExitTransition: AnimatedContentTransitionScope<NavBackStackEntry>.() -> ExitTransition = exitTransition,
    builder: NavGraphBuilder.() -> Unit
): Unit
```

The important one in this case is the `route` parameter, which defaults to `null`. This is the route of the root graph.

Because your `composable("scan")` and `composable("config")` screens aren't contained within any [nested navigation graph](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav), they are both direct children of that root graph.

That means when you do `destination.parent?.route` you are getting the exact `route` that you've set on your whole `NavHost`...which is `null`. That means you are going down the `return` koinViewModel()` path and never actually scoping your navigation graph to a parent graph.

The easiest way to fix this is to actually provide a `route` to the `NavHost` to use for the root navigation graph:

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "scan", route = "root") {
```